# Can´t generate a JAR file properly

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am generating a .JAR from an app. I can run the app from NetBeans with no problem, but when I generate the .JAR it's impossible to open it.

I've selected the right main class in the properties, so I don't really know why this happens.

When I try to execute the .JAR it just pops up, and then closes in a blink.

The `main()` selection:

[image: The main selected]

Comment: Run it from the command line and see what the error message is.

Comment: how do I run it? I mean, if I run the .JAR form netbeans it runs correctly

Comment: `java -jar yourjarfile.jar`

Comment: okay, I ran it and it says no main manifest attribute, but in the properties of the project I already chose the main class, Im attaching it to the post wait a sec

Comment: Look at the actual files in the jar, and the contents of the manifest file.